# How can I connect 2 Arduinos using ESP8266 transiver: ESP01

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have: 2 arduinos UNO, 2 ESP01 transivers. But if that's not enough, I'm ready to buy something else
I need to use one of Arduinos as a wifi hot spot, and the second as a modem. They should just be connected to each other :)
P.S. This is for my school project! Subsequently, I will put some obstacles between the Arduinos to see how much the signal strength degrades.

Comment: what research have you done for your school project?

Comment: Have you googled for how to use these with an Uno? Have you searched for libraries, that make it easier? Have you tried writing a program for the Uno? Have you searched for tutorials on how to setup an access point and how to connect to an access point?

Comment: Thank you very much for corrective questions. I'm from Russia, so I wanted to find content that could help me in the most accessible way - in Russian. But, on the Russian-speaking Internet, there are very small amount of people who are really interested in this topic. Most of the tutorials rested on controlling the Arduino with a phone via wifi, but this is not exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the ESP8266 WiFi library:
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi

In there You'll find an example for a WiFi access point:
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiAccessPoint/WiFiAccessPoint.ino

And an example for WiFi client:
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiClient/WiFiClient.ino

That should provide enough information for you to build your project.

To get the signal strength without connecting, you can use WiFiScan:
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiScan/WiFiScan.ino

Comment: Thanks a lot a lot a lot!!! Do you have any information about how to correctly connect modules with arduinos?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=esp8266+arduino+wiring